# What is a PID as is related to quadcopters

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, pid, microcontroller

I'm trying to make a Quadcopter from scratch, I have a fair amount of experience with adruinos, and I'm trying to understand how to necessary systems work, and I can't seem to figure out what PID means, is it a method of regulating pitch and roll? like a stabilizer? I think from what I've read that its a system that detects orientation of the craft and tries to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term PID itself refers to Proportional plus Integral plus Derivative control, which is a very common control technique. The IMU (inertial measurement unit) measures the orientation of the quadrotor, and the roll/pitch/yaw values are used in the PID controller to calculate motor commands.

Comment: So the pid takes the output of the imu and sends the appropriate command to the motors?

Comment: Basically, yes. There are also some user-defined tuning variables to adjust how strong the motor command is relative to the error.